# Error R Session Aborted

Tags: r, rstudio

Estaba practicando modelo predictivo con randomForest y RStudio aborta la sesión. El error se produce cuando corre la última línea, al tratar de crear el modelo predictivo.

Éste es el mensaje de error:

"R session aborted
R encountered a fatal error.
The session was terminated.
Start New Session"

El archivo es un dataframe .csv con 157 filas y 14 columnas.

Si sirve, estoy usando Ubuntu 22.04 "jammy" y mi RStudio es 4.1.2 "Bird Hippie".

Éste es el código:

```
library(tidyverse)  
library(funModeling)  
  
df <- read_csv("/home/gustavo/DatosVivos/R/R_proy_y_data_20200827/data/winemag-data_first150k.csv")  
  
status(df) # Vemos qué columnas tienen problemas  
df_2=df %>% mutate_if(is.character, replace_na, replace = "nulo")  
status(df_2) # Verificación  
  
valor_mean <- round(mean(df_2$price, na.rm = TRUE), 0) # Ya sé que el promedio no es  
                                                       # la mejor opción pero era para  
                                                       # salir del paso  
df_2$price <- df$price %>% replace(is.na(.),valor_mean)  
status(df_2) # Verificación  
  
df_2$mayor_menor <- 0 # Creo columna para trabajar sólo con dos valores  
  
for (i in 1:length(df_2$...1)) { # Recorremos el archivo y ponemos "1" en  
  if (df_2$points[i] >= 90) {    # la columna "mayor_menor" cuando  
    df_2$mayor_menor[i] <- 1     # la columna "points" sea mayor o igual a 90  
  }  
}  
  
df_2$mayor_menor <- as.factor(df_2$mayor_menor) # Pasamos a factor los 0s y 1s  
vct <- get_sample(df_2, percentage_tr_rows = 0.8) # Vector aleatorio para extraer filas  
  
data_tr <- df_2[vct, ]   # Data frame para entrenamientro  
data_ts <- df_2[-vct, ]  # Data frame para validación  
  
library(randomForest)  
  
data_x <- select(data_tr, -mayor_menor) # DF exeptuando la columna "mayor_menor"  
data_y <- data_tr$mayor_menor           # Vector columna "mayor_menor"  
  
fit <- randomForest(x = data_x, y = data_y) # ... Y aquí es donde surge el problema,  
                                            # RStudio se "cuelga", se tilda y pide reiniciar sesión
```

Comment: ¿Que estás realizando cuando manda el mensaje de error?

Comment: Hola Gustavo, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta elimina la imagen, y agrega tu código y el mensaje de error como texto, gracias..

Comment: @Jorgesys, sencillamente corriendo el programa, todo viene bien hasta que ejecuta 
 `fit <- randomForest(x = data_x, y = data_y)`.